# How to create a separate gemset in a Middleman project?

Tags: rbenv, middleman

Using rbenv for managing my rubies, and wondering what the preferred way was to have a separate gemset for each of my Middleman projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User rbenv-gemset. It's designed to work with rbenv, and you can do everything you need to do gemset-wise.